# Процесс шифрования

Tags: запрос, сетевое-программирование

Как происходит процесс  шифрования, а точнее как безопасно передать ключ собеседнику?
Я нашел множество вариантов как можно зашифровать сообщение, но не могу понять как безопасно передать ключ шифра!
Спасибо!

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB_%D0%94%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8_%E2%80%94_%D0%A5%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0

Comment: Шифрование информации происходит по определенному алгоритму. В использованном алгоритме часто используется ключь. Также ключь использует принемающая сторона, для дешифровки информации. Шифрование информации бывает симметричное и асимметричное. Подробнее можете почитать здесь) https://codeby.net/threads/nachinajuschim-kriptografija-vvedenie.61349/

Answer (score 0):

Никак потому что [mitm](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0). Именно поэтому для проверки подлинности сертификатов в каждой ОС есть заранее предустановленный набор корневых сертификатов.

Но если речь идёт о практическом применении, а не теоретически о шифровании в общем, то надо использовать защищённые каналы передачи данных, например https. Ну и для этого надо иметь сертификат, выданный доверенным центром.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете поступить следующим образом:

1. Вы и ваш собеседник генерируете ключи шифрования ( открытые и закрытые, у каждого свои )
2. Вы передаете собеседнику Ваш открытый ключ шифрования
3. Ваш собеседник шифрует вашим открытым ключом свои ключи и передает вам
4. Вы расшифровываете его сообщение своим закрытым ключом
5. Теперь вы и ваш собеседник владеете одними ключами шифрования ( в данном случае теми, что сгенерировал ваш собеседник)

Comment: Но от mitm это не спасёт.

Comment: @Qwertiy я не специалист по инфобезу, приведите пожалуйста пример атаки на такой алгоритм, ознакомления ради

Comment: Обычный mitm же. Между тобой и получателем сидит злоумышленник и вместо все действия выполняет сам, а с получателем общается сам.

Comment: @Qwertiy точно, что-то сглупил :)  тогда у атакующего получается двойная работа: дешифрование от источника одним ключом и шифрование для получателя другим ключом

Comment: Да, именно так.